# Redirecting all traffic to a script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, infinite-loop

I am on Centos 6.5 with Apache2 and Perl 5.23. I need to pass all traffic to the single perl script, check this request in a database, and show needed content (have both static and dynamic content).

The problem is I don't know how not to get caught to the infinite loop in mod_rewrite.

F.e. first time I pass a request to a script script sees that the user needs a static content and redirects it to the needed page, but this way the user gets to the .htaccess rules again.

I thought to add some kind of a parameter, but not sured. Need your help!

Comment: You might get better answers on [webmasters.se].